# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'sympy' has no attribute 'S' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, sympy, attributeerror

This is my code

```
x,t = sympy.S('x,t')

def dawson(i):
    x = i
    expression = sympy.E**(-x**2) * sympy.integrate(sympy.E**(t**2),t,0,x)
    return sympy.lamdify(expression)
```

but I get that weird error when I execute it, and this is the first time this is happening. Why is sympy *partially* initialized and what does a circular import mean here?

Comment: Circular import generally means that module A imports module B, and module B also imports module A.  If you showed us your imports, perhaps we could be of more help.

Comment: I just imported sympy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really sure if this would be of help, but posting this an answer because this error happened to me for me with a different module `requests (python -m pip install requests)` and this is how I fixed it.

This happened to me because I named the file `random.py` which also happens to be the name of a module in python's stdlib.

MCVE

```
import requests
requests.get(None)
```

Save the file as `random.py` and run.

`AttributeError: partially initialized module 'requests' has no attribute 'get' (most likely due to a circular import)`

Renaming the file to a different name solved this problem for me.

So my guess is do not name your file the same as any of python's stdlib module and do not have any `.py` files that are named the same in your current working directory as well (unlikely if you follow the previous suggestion in the first place).

Comment: Thanks I had a file named sympy.py